# Create function or macros for setup structure

Tags: ios

I have structure

```
struct CounterRange {
    NSInteger min;
    NSInteger max;
};
```

I want set params for structure like in NSMakeRange:

```
NSMakeRange(unsigned int loc, unsigned int len)
```

so the code line will look like below

```
obj.counterRange = MakeCounterRange(10, 20);
```

As I think e.g. MakeCounterRange will be a macros that will set structure for me. But I have never made the same things I just can suppose how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a function. You can make it inline if you want. You can adapt the definition of NSMakeRange from NSRange.h:

```
NS_INLINE NSRange NSMakeRange(NSUInteger loc, NSUInteger len) {
    NSRange r;
    r.location = loc;
    r.length = len;
    return r;
}
```

Your struct looks a lot like NSRange. Why don't you just use that?

Comment: yes thanks, I just have seen how it organize and create my own inline macros.

Comment: NS_INLINE CounterRange MakeCounterRange(NSUInteger min, NSUInteger max) I have created it like this. is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
#define MakeCounterRange(a, b) { a, b }
```

NOTE: Macros generally make things easier, allowing things to be achieved with fewer characters.  That isn't the case here, so I wouldn't even bother using it.